# Como acessar objetos de uma classe dentro de um método anônimo?

Tags: php

Pesquisei muito na internet mas não encontrei em como desenvolver, serei muito grato por quem puder me tirar essa dúvida.
Gostaria de desenvolver uma classe em php onde fosse possível acessar seus métodos dentro de um método anônimo conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
MyClass::method('param1', function($class){
    $class->print('Hello World');
});
```

Este exemplo de utilização eu encontrei no Laravel em sua classe Mail, exemplo:

```
Mail::send('emails.reminder', ['user' => $user], function ($m) use ($user) {
    $m->from('hello@app.com', 'Your Application');
    $m->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Your Reminder!');
});
```

Comment: Você quer que `MyClass::method` vire automaticamente uma instancia `new MyClass` e seja passado como valor para `$class`? Qual o propósito disto? Orientação a objetos é usado para organizar e quando necessário, se for simplesmente por "beleza" que você esta querendo fazer isso já logo lhe digo que está usando mal a *Orientação a objetos*

Comment: Olá, eu editei minha pergunta para ser mais específico, na verdade eu encontrei esse exemplo de utilização na classe Mail do Laravel, gostaria de tirar uma dúvida de como desenvolver uma classe que se utiliza exatamente dessa forma para estudar mesmo. Obrigado

Comment: Mas aquilo ali tem um proposito, você quer usar algo mesmo sem um propositio? O `$m` retorna uma instancia de message para interagir com vosso controller, quero dizer é totalmente possivel você fazer isso, se olhar no 5.5 eles até mudaram a abordagem https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mail... Quero dizer na verdade é simples, só que fazer por fazer não dá pra dizer que é uma grande utilidade pro uso do OO. Vou tentar bolar um exemplo aqui.

Comment: Propósito eu até tenho, mas não posso colocá-las em prática sem antes de entender o conceito e a melhor maneira de se fazer, obrigado pelas dicas está sendo de grande ajuda.

Comment: Só me dizer duas coisas: 1. você sabe a diferença de uma instancia e de um "estático"? 2. Você precisa que o $class em `function($class)` seja auto-instanciavel para cada vez que usar `MyClass::method` ou você quer que ele crie uma instancia unica?

Comment: Respondendo a pergunta 1: sim, 2 sim.

Comment: Última pergunta: a função anônima deve possuir acesso apenas aos elementos públicos da classe ou poderá acessar métodos privados?

Comment: Seguindo a lógica acima acredito que faça mais sentido que ele acesse somente os métodos públicos da classe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a função anônima possuir acesso apenas aos elementos públicos, sejam atributos ou métodos da classe, o código será basicamente o que o Guilherme descreveu nos comentários: um método estático que cria uma nova instância da classe e a passa como parâmetro para a função anônima. Simples assim. Veja um exemplo:

```
class Groot {

    private function __construct() {
        $this->name = "I'm groot!";
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public static function create($callback) {

        // Cria uma nova instância da classe:
        $new = new self();

        // Invoca a função anônima passando a instância como parâmetro:
        $callback($new);

    }

}


Groot::create(function ($self) {
    echo $self->getName(), PHP_EOL;
});
```

<sup>Veja em funcionamento no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/tKPfeG) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MGgU/0)</sup>

Para que a função anônima tenha acesso aos elementos privados, você precisará associar a função ao objeto através do `Closure::bind`. Veja um exemplo:

```
class Groot {

    private $name;

    private function __construct() {
        $this->name = "I'm groot!";
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public static function create($callback) {

        // Cria uma nova instância da classe:
        $new = new self();

        // Associa a função ao objeto:
        $callback = Closure::bind($callback, null, $new);

        // Invoca a função anônima passando a instância como parâmetro:
        $callback($new);

    }

}


Groot::create(function ($self) {
    echo $self->name, PHP_EOL;
});
```

<sup>Veja em funcionamento no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Omv1q7) | [Repl.it](https://repl.it/MGhx/0)</sup>

Mesmo `$name` sendo um atributo privado, a função anônima terá acesso ao mesmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica amigo, isso me ajudou bastante, estarei estudando mais sobre esse tipo de abordagem.